# Filtering events aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

**Заголовок вопроса:**
Проблемы с логическим 'AND' в фильтрах aiogram 3.2

**Тело вопроса:**
Я использую aiogram версии 3.2 для создания Telegram-бота и столкнулся с проблемой при фильтрации callback-ивентов. Я хочу, чтобы мой обработчик событий срабатывал только тогда, когда выполняются два условия, но сталкиваюсь с трудностями при реализации логического 'AND'.

Вот пример моего кода:

```py
from aiogram import F, Router
from aiogram.types import CallbackQuery, Message
from aiogram.filters.callback_data import CallbackData
# [Остальные импорты опущены для краткости]

class ExampleData(CallbackData, prefix='foo'):
    action: str
    id: int

# [Остальной код опущен для краткости]

@router.callback_query(
    ExampleData.filter(
        F.action == 'help',
        F.id == 0
    )
)
async def com_annswer(cb: CallbackQuery, callback_data: CallbackData):
    # [Обработка события]
```

Когда я использую фильтр `ExampleData.filter(F.action == 'help', F.id == 0)`, я получаю ошибку `TypeError: CallbackData.filter() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`. Однако, когда я изменяю его на `ExampleData.filter(F.action == 'help' and F.id == 0)`, условие работает как 'OR', срабатывая, если хотя бы одно из условий верно.

Как мне корректно реализовать логическое 'AND' в этом контексте?

То есть `com_annswer()` среагирует если `F.action == 'lol'` но `F.id == 0`

Answer (score 1):

**Нашел решение.**

Чтобы фильтровать с помощью 'AND' нужно использовать примерно такой код

```
@router.callback_query(
    ExampleData.filter(F.action == 'skip'),
    ExampleData.filter(F.id == 0), # Вынесен отдельно
)
```

*То есть не в одном фильтре задавать условия `(F.1 and F.2)`, а `filter(F.1) filter(F.2)`.*